# Creating Octal NumberSpinner in Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo, octal

I am trying to restrict dijit.form.NumberSpinner so that it will only accept an Octal Number between 0 and 0777.

I tried to do this by setting the Constraints in the constructor and then overriding the adjust(...) function of NumberSpinner. In my HTML page I have:

```
<input name="umask" id="umask" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.NumberSpinner"
value="022" data-dojo-props="smallDelta:1, largeDelta:4,
constraints:{min:0, max:777, places:0},
adjust: function(val, delta) { octalAdjust(val, delta, this.constraints); }"/>
```

And in my included JavaScript I have:

```
function octalAdjust(val, delta, constraints) {
     ...
 return newval;
};
```

The problem that I have is that when I click the 'up' or 'down' button on the numeric spinner, my octalAdjust functions is called over and over again for ever. I have no idea why it gets called repetitively?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In your `adjust` function, you're not returning the value of `octalAdjust` - you're just calling it. Change your `adjust` override like so:

```
adjust: function(val, delta) { return octalAdjust(val, delta, this.constraints); }
```

Comment: So I added in the 'return' as suggested. However my octalAdjust function is still called if I click the up button on the spinner, and its called over and over again, but this time it causes my spinner to be incremented by 1 each time. This happens very quickly, and the spinner quickly counts up. I tried to reproduce this here - [http://jsfiddle.net/mW9Rb/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/mW9Rb/5/) but it seems to work fine outside of my main code-base. Does anyone else have any suggestions...